# I have vaulted card information in BlueSnap through the API - how do I retrieve it?

Tags: bluesnap

I am using the BlueSnap Payment API and have vaulted cards in BlueSnap. Once the information is stored, how do I retrieve the vaulted card information from BlueSnap?

Answer (score 1):

Vaulted information can be retrieved using the Retrieve Vaulted Shopper API. More information can be found here: http://developers.bluesnap.com/v2.0/docs/retrieve-vaulted-shopper

Note that BlueSnap will never return the full card number due to PCI compliance. The API only returns the last 4 digits, exp. date, and card type in the response. If you want to retrieve the full card data you need to contact BlueSnap at merchants@bluesnap.com and they will explain the process of how to retrieve the vaulted card data (they will only provide that data in a secure fashion to a PCI certified entity).